# Cannot connect to MySQL server inside Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, database-connection, port

First I run mysql image:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password  -d  -p 127.0.0.1:3308:3306 mysql
```

Then I use container bash:

```
docker exec -it my_container_name bash
```

In Bash I can successfully connect to MySQL server via command:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

But when I try to connect to MySQL container from Windows cmd:

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 -P3308

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)
```

If I connect to `192.168.99.100` instead (this ip is returned by `docker-machine ip`), then the result is the same.

The question is: How do I correctly expose my MySQL port inside Docker to outside Windows?

Comment: If you're using Docker Machine, you have to use the Docker Machine VM's IP address instead of 127.0.0.1: `mysql -uroot -ppassword -h192.168.99.100 -P3308`. 192.168.99.100 typically is the IP of the Docker Machine VM.

Comment: nwinkler indeed, 192.168.99.100 is returned buy  docker-machine ip command. But it replacing ip doesn't help

Comment: Can you run `docker ps -a` to check that the port mapping is set up in the right way?

Comment: @nwinkler it returns 127.0.0.1:3308->3306/tcp for mysql image

Comment: Can you try to remove the `127.0.0.1` from the `docker run` command? `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password  -d  -p 3308:3306 mysql`

Comment: @nwinkler yes it helped! You saved my day. Thanks a lot. If you post an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is in your port mapping in the original `docker run` command, you just need to provide the ports, not the IP address:

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d -p 3308:3306 mysql
```

You can run `docker ps -a` to check for the port mapping in the running containers.

You should now be able to connect to MySQL using

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword -h192.168.99.100 -P3308
```

Comment: For everyone that made it here the same way I did.. the default auth schema has changed in mysql8 so if you still can't login maybe try `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d -p 3308:3306 mysql:5.7` <-- NOTE the 5.7

Comment: it worked only when adding spaces 
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308

Comment: why cant i do 3306:3306 ?

Answer (score 0):

First, check `netstat -an` to make sure the port is open in Windows.  If it is, also check the Windows firewall to make sure nothing is blocking connections to the port.

Most of my Docker experience is in CoreOS, so I'm not exactly sure how Windows handles routing traffic into the container.  In CoreOS, it uses a [proxy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/).  If there is a proxy in Windows, make sure nothing is interfering with it.

Comment: it's not open, it's not even mentioned in the netstat -an output

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port in which I was running the image worked.
I checked if this port was used by something else, but it was not used. so I just -desperately- run a new container in a different port '3309'. and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have entered the port with -P.